# explain $CI =& get_instance();

Tags: php, codeigniter

Looking through codeigniter's source code,

in its helper functions I keep seeing code
`$CI =& get_instance();`
can anyone please explain to me how this code works?

I get that it is returning a reference to the $CI super object, but where does `get_instance()` come from?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403 to understand why you shouldn't write `=&` anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's basically a [Singleton Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) that uses a function instead of a static method.

To look deeper, check out the [source code](http://web.archive.org/web/20120115022552/http://docs.gipertext.com/framework/ci170/d3/d9b/Base5_8php-source.html)

So basically, it doesn't enforce the singleton, but it's a shortcut to a public function...

**Edit:** Actually, now I understand.  For PHP4 compatibility they had to do a [double-global-variable-hack](http://web.archive.org/web/20111210230932/http://docs.gipertext.com/framework/ci170/d6/dea/Base4_8php-source.html) to get it to return the references properly.  Otherwise the references would get all screwed up.  And since PHP4 didn't have support for static methods (well, properly anyway), using the function was the better way.  So it still exists for legacy reasons...

So if your app is PHP5 only, there *should* be nothing wrong with doing `CI_Base::get_instance();` instead, it's identical...

Comment: When to use CI super object and why ? Can you point me to some CI documentation regarding the CI super object ?

Comment: +1 for actually pointing to the **REPLACEMENT** usage for `$CI =& get_instance();` I was banging my face on the Docs looking for that...

Comment: @Bugfixer When you see that 404 error please edit  that link using http://web.archive.org. Already done for that link

Answer (score 21):

get_instance() is a function defined in the core files of CodeIgniter.  You use it to get the singleton reference to the CodeIgniter super object when you are in a scope outside of the super object.

I'm pretty sure it's defined in base.php or something similar.

Comment: Simple and exact explanation that I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Only the class that extends CI_Controller,Model,View can use

```
$this->load->library('something');
$this->load->helper('something');//..etc
```

Your Custom Class cannot use the above code.
To use the above features in your custom class, your must use

```
$CI=&get instance();
$CI->load->library('something');
$CI->load->helper('something');
```

for example,in your custom class

```
// this following code will not work
Class Car
{
   $this->load->library('something');
   $this->load->helper('something');
}

//this will work
Class Car
{
   $CI=&get_instance();
   $CI->load->library('something');
   $CI->load->helper('something');
}
// Here $CI is a variable.
```

Answer (score 4):

this is a singleton structure to understand how the codeigniter loads the libraries and classes

```php
<?php

/*
====================================
start of the loader class
====================================
*/
class Loader {


  protected function _init_class($class){
    $C = Controller::get_instance();
    $name = strtolower($class);
    $C->$name = new $class();
  }

  public function _class($library){
    if(is_array($library)){
      foreach($library as $class){
        $this->library($class);
      }
      return;
    }

    if($library == ''){
      return false;
    }

    $this->_init_class($library);
  }

  public function view ($param) {
     echo $param;
  }
}
/*
===============================
 End of the loader class
==============================
*/

/*
===============================
 start of core controller class
==============================
*/

class Controller {

  private static  $instance;

  function __construct () {
    self::$instance = $this;
    $this->load = new Loader();
  }


  public static function get_instance(){
    return self::$instance;
  }
}
/*
===============================
end of the core controller class
=================================== 
*/

/*
 ====================================================
  start of library sections (put all your library classes in this section)
=====================================================
*/

class MyLibrary {

 private $c;

 function __construct() {
   $this->c = Controller::get_instance();
 }

 function say($sentence) {
   $this->c->load->view($sentence);
 }
}
/*
 ====================================================
  End of the library sections
====================================================
*/

/*
 ============================================
  start of controller section (put all your controller classes in this section)
 ===========================================
*/

class Foo extends Controller {

  function __construct () {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->_class('MyLibrary');
  }

  function bar() {
    $this->mylibrary->say('Hello World');
  }
}


/* 
 ==========================================
  End of the controller sections
 ==========================================
*/

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

$CI = get_instance(); is to replace $this to $CI on helper,

Comment: but you must definition your helper on autoload [library]

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in the constructor worked for me:

```
function __construct()
{
$this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```