# codeigniter override set_value function in form helper using MY_helper to repopulate fields at get,post both

Tags: php, codeigniter

codeigniter override set_value function in form helper using MY_helper to repopulate fields at get,post both and while not validating. i am using version of ci is 2.0.3
i created My_form_helper.php in application/helpers/ and added function

```
function set_value($field = '', $default = '')
{   
    if (FALSE === ($OBJ =& _get_validation_object()))
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            return form_prep($_POST[$field], $field);
        }
        if (isset($_GET[$field]))
        {
            return form_prep($_GET[$field], $field);
        }

        return $default;
    }

    return form_prep($OBJ->set_value($field, $default), $field);
}
```

but its not working.

in autoload.php i am doing this ->
  $autoload['helper'] = array('html','form','url','my','text','MY_form');
it says unable to load my_form_helper.php

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? errors? blank values? what? Also, how do you call this helper?

Comment: @DamienPirsy in autoload.php in application/config helper added.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740430/explain-ci-get-instance useful here but instance not used set_value function

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem with Capital letters in helper file names. It appears that codeigniter converts helper names to all lowercase and then finds the file.

Try helper file: `my_form_helper.php` and then check. It should work.

Comment: yes it is, in custom helper we create instance is that kind of thing needed in above function, there directly isset($_GET[$field]) used.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your comment but my answer was pertaining to CodeIgniter complaining "unable to load my_form_helper.php". It might be because you have capital letter in your helper file name. Try changing it to all lowercase and CodeIgniter should be able to load it.

Comment: oho please have a look at function, hint: in helper we don't use $this like in view/controller