# Get cookie value in my CodeIgniter helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am having a weird issue with cookies in CodeIgniter. The problem is I am able to use `set_cookie()` inside my custom helper, however I am unable to get data from a cookie?  I get the following error:

**Call to undefined function cookie()**

**EDIT**

Okay I figured out how to fix this problem.

I needed to do the following:

```
$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->input->cookie('cookie name')
```

**However,** I still don't understand why you can set a cookie with using $CI, but you have to use $CI to retrieve it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740430/explain-ci-get-instance) relating to your question.

> It's basically a Singleton Design Pattern that uses a function instead of a static method.