# Why keep getting an Undefined property on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load a model in a library.

This is how I am loading it,

```
class Init{
 private $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model("backend/StoreSettings_Model");
    }
}
```

When I try to access the method in the storesettings_model, I get the following error `Undefined property: Init::$Storesettings_Model`

```
 public function settingsSetUp($store_name){

      $settings =   $this->CI->storesettings_model->getStoreSettings($store_name);

}
```

I have tried the changing the case to match the case of the class I am loading to StoreSettings_Model... still same problem

If I load the library with all lower case then it will work, but then when I upload to my development server which runs on Linux, it will throw an error because the class name is `StoreSettings_Model` and the im instantiating with `storesettings_model`

Has anyone face this issue before? If so what do you suggest about fixing it?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have named your model wrong instead of StoreSettings_Model try `Storesettings_model.php` for file name and `class Storesettings_model extends CI_Model {}` only first letter should be upper case. `$this->CI->load->model('backend/storesettings_model')`

Comment: On here `$this->CI = &get_instance();` you have a space on the right side of the `= &` try like `$this->CI =&get_instance();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740430/explain-ci-get-instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function __construct()
{
    #  $this->CI = &get_instance(); < ---- remove this 
    $this->load->model("backend/StoreSettings_Model"); # remove CI-> 
}
```

in Method

```
 public function settingsSetUp($store_name){

      $settings =   $this->storesettings_model->getStoreSettings($store_name);  # remove CI-> on here too

}
```